# Creating timestamps throws an error for model with dynamic table name set in constructor

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have an Eloquent model with constructor (below), that takes `$type` param. The types are - let's say - `first`, `second` or `third`.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model {

    protected $table; // Define $table field

    public function __construct($type = null, array $attributes = array()) {

        // Initialize $table field
        $this->table = isset($type) ? 'my_'.$type.'_table' : null;

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

?>
```

As you can see in the code above, I set the model's `$table` property to `my_[type]_table`, so I can use the model dynamically with one of 3 tables available. Like this:

```
// Somewhere in controller
$type = 'first';
$myModel = new MyModel($type);
$myModel->create(.....); // <= Error is thrown here
```

**The problem is** when Eloquent tries to create timestamps for the table, it doesn't care anymore about the table name I set in `__construct()` and it tries to create the timestamps for table called `my_models` (which is obviously based on the model's class name), instead of doing it for (in this case) `my_first_table`:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: my_models (SQL:
>   insert into "my_models" ("updated_at", "created_at") values
>   (2015-07-17 08:35:13, 2015-07-17 08:35:13))

Any way to keep the dynamic table name for the automatic timestamps creation? Im on Laravel 5.1.

Comment: What are you doing so that Eloquent generates such an insert? Could you paste a piece of code that results in this error being generated?

Comment: It's the `$myModel->create(.....);` part. Basically it tries to create the entry but breaks when it comes to timestamps.

Comment: Are the types dynamic or more than 20? If no I would create a common base class for these models with their common implementation and only change `$table` in the descendant classes.
This documents better what models are available by looking at the classes and also provides a cleaner solution if you need to one day implement things differently per table.

Answer (score 1):

When you call **$myModel->create()**, a new object is created and type is not passed to its constructor.

Just pass $type to **$myModel->create()** as one of the attributes, update the constructor:

```
public function __construct($attributes = array()) {
  if (array_key_exists('type', $attributes)) {
    $this->table = 'my_' . $attributes['type'] . '_model';
  }

  parent::__construct(array_except($attributes, 'type'));
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: By default you pass array of attributes to the `create()` method. Should I then do it like that? `$myModel->create('first', ['field1' => value1, 'field2' => value2]);` I don't see `create()` taking other params than the array in Laravel's API.

Comment: $myModel->create(['type => 'first', 'field1' => value1, 'field2' => value2]);

Comment: What you suggest is passing `type` as a column name, with a value `first`. No such column of course in my table.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is I don't use `MyModel` only for creating. Basically, everytime I *want* to use the model, I need to set the correct table name - regardless of whether this is a read or write operation. This means, I always need to pass the `type` to the constructor. I could do what you propose and this would work, but I find it a bit "hacky". E.g. what if I wanted to introduce a new real *type* column to my tables? ;) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you're trying to do something that Eloquent doesn't offer. What you need is table inheritance, it's something other ORMs offer, but Laravel doesn't have it yet. You could try to implement it yourself - you can see an example here http://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2014-eloquent-single-table-inheritance

Comment: Nice, will give it a look later. Thx.

Comment: Alternative solution from the future: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47987005/10441671

Answer (score 1):

a bit late

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model {


    //-- using a mutator
    public function setTypeAttribute($type)
    {

        //-- set type =)
        $this->attributes['type'] = $type;

        //-- then use this type for your table name convention
        $this->setTable( 'my_'. $type .'_table' );

    }
}

?>
```