# How to dynamically set table name in Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am trying to use Eloquent Model to access data in DB.

I have tables that shares similarities such as table name.

So I want to use one Model to access several tables in DB like below but without luck.

Is there any way to set table name dynamically?

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Model:**

```
class ProductLog extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function __construct($type = null) {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->setTable($type);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index($type, $id) {

    $productLog = new ProductLog($type);

    $contents = $productLog::all();

    return response($contents, 200);
}
```

**Solution For those who suffer from same problem:**

I was able to change table name by the way @Mahdi Younesi suggested.

And I was able to add where conditions by like below

```
$productLog = new ProductLog;
$productLog->setTable('LogEmail');

$logInstance = $productLog->where('origin_id', $carrier_id)
                          ->where('origin_type', 2);
```

Comment: so, you want to pass different table name every time?

Comment: Yes. Only for certain tables; tables with similar attributes.

Comment: I can suggest that you make models for all the tables but I can tell you a common function which will make object of any model by passing just model name to that function and you will get the model object dynamically.

Comment: If this is absolutely necessary you can override the `getTable` method, but you might be able to use Query Scopes and set the table name inside of them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following trait allows for passing on the table name during hydration.

```
trait BindsDynamically
{
    protected $connection = null;
    protected $table = null;

    public function bind(string $connection, string $table)
    {
       $this->setConnection($connection);
       $this->setTable($table);
    }

    public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false)
    {
       // Overridden in order to allow for late table binding.

       $model = parent::newInstance($attributes, $exists);
       $model->setTable($this->table);

       return $model;
    }

}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
class ProductLog extends Model
{
   use BindsDynamically;
}
```

Call the method on instance like this:

```
public function index() 
{
   $productLog = new ProductLog;

   $productLog->setTable('anotherTableName');

   $productLog->get(); // select * from anotherTableName


   $productLog->myTestProp = 'test';
   $productLog->save(); // now saves into anotherTableName
}
```

Comment: It changes table name but after I use `$productLog->setTable('anotherTableName');`, if I were to use `$productLog->where('some query')`, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I created a package for this: `Laravel Dynamic Model`

Feel free to use it:
https://github.com/laracraft-tech/laravel-dynamic-model

This basically allows you to do something like this:

```
$foo = App::make(DynamicModel::class, ['table_name' => 'foo']);

$foo->create([
    'col1' => 'asdf',
    'col2' => 123
]);

$faz = App::make(DynamicModel::class, ['table_name' => 'faz']);
$faz->create([...]);
```