# Eloquent ORM dynamic table, creating via model fails to select table

Tags: php, eloquent

On the REST API am building based on slim3, I use route parameters to dynamically select a tenant to do certain crud actions on.

The model:

```
class Customer extends Model {
    protected $table = '';
    protected $fillable = ['some', 'fields'];

    public function setTable($table) {
        $this->table = $table;
    }
    public function getTable() {
        return $this->table;
    }
}
```

Selecting and updating entries works (properly) like this:

```
// selects properly from $tableName table
$kd = new Customer;
$kd->setTable($tableName);
$data = $kd->whereEmail($args['email'])->firstOrFail();
```

Creation fails, using the same approach:

```
$kdc = new Customer;
$kdc->setTable($tableName); // it should use dbname.prefix_$tableName same as above
$kdc->create($customerData);
// fails with error Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.prefix_' doesn't exist
```

I have checked that create() successfully calls getTable() from the Model and gets proper value. But it seems not to use it...

Comment: Take a look here on how to set the table name dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986628/how-to-dynamically-set-table-name-in-eloquent-model

Comment: I didn't find this answered question, but it fixes my problem, thanks alot!