# Laravel - can I make models dynamically and have relationships on each generated model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to create Models based on the alphabet as their tables names are like `'products_a', 'products_b'....'products_z'`. But I don't want to create all these models as separated files,
but want to find a way to use all these tables dynamically.
And all tables are separated based on some 'shopping-mall id' values.

I've found a solution to set tables dynamically like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986628/how-to-dynamically-set-table-name-in-eloquent-model/47987005).

So what I tried before was like below.

```
class Products extends Model
{
    use BindsDynamically;

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $fillable = [ 'product_name', 'reg_time'];

    public static function newProduct($mall_id)
    {
        $rangeArr = range('a', 'z');

        $product = new Products;

        foreach ($rangeArr as $ar) {
            if (strtolower(substr($mall_id, 0, 1)) == $ar) {
                $product->setTable('product_'.$ar);
            }
        }

        return $product;
    }
}
```

However, now I created a Cart model and tried to use the relationship methods with all the separated tables which I cannot.
So I realized I need the separated models with relationships not just tables.

Theoretically, my database has those tables.

products_a
products_b
....
products_z
products_cart

So, the `products_cart` table needs to have all the products tables `idx` data.
I want to use relationships like 'hasMany' or 'belongsTo', therefore I need all the separated models.

Can I make all the alphabetical models dynamically and use relationship methods?
If so, how can I do this?

**OK, I understand we have a nasty DB design here.** But then, we don't have a DB expert and I cannot figure what can I do about this DB design.
So, please don't judge about the DB design, rather guide the better way to replace it.

Comment: You shouldn't have your tables set up like that. Have a read about [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). I'd suggest moving all the products into a `products` table with a column which distinguishes `a` products from `b` products from `c` products, etc.

Comment: Sounds like bad database design

Comment: I know it would be bad DB design, but we would have probably over billions of data for each tables, so we decided that we should have all the products data to separated tables.

Comment: And also, it was already designed like that, I don't have the authority to change that decision.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you `UNION` all product tables and overwrite the models `newModelQuery()` method to achieve that

```php
class Products extends Model
{
    use BindsDynamically;

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $fillable = [ 'product_name', 'reg_time'];

    /**
     * Get a new query builder that doesn't have any global scopes or eager loading.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
     */
    public function newModelQuery()
    {
        $query = parent::newModelQuery();

        $rangeArr = range('a', 'z');

        foreach ($rangeArr as $ar) {
            //if (strtolower(substr($mall_id, 0, 1)) == $ar) {
                $query->union('product_'.$ar);
            //}
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

But that's probably just one of a couple methods you'd have to overwrite this way. And this solution currently doesn't support your `$mall_id`. But after all, it's due to bad database design.

Comment: If this answer cannot take the ```$mall_id``` as a parameter, how is this better than the code I already wrote in my question? I asked about the dynamic model that can have any relationship. Sorry but I don't understand what you suggest on here.

Comment: These are two different approaches. Eloquent expects two models of the same class to have the same table. Your approach doesn't follow that principle. Therefore, I implemented that behavoir by acting as if all the product tables were one.